# FlaskLogin Making Database Queries Every Page Load

Tags: database, authentication, flask

I have the regular old code (no surprises).

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    print 'loading user'
    return connection.db.Users.find_one( { '_id' : ObjectId(user_id) } )
```

Evaluation of this demonstrates that it loads the user—thus querying the database—every time the page changes. What can I do to alleviate the load of the database?

Edit. The code works. There's nothing wrong other than I'd like to reduce the database load.

Comment: If you want some cache, take a look at flask-cache. You can just cache (memoize) your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading the user from the database with every request is pretty standard.

The reason is that web servers are stateless, once they process a request they forget about it completely. When a new request comes information provided with the request such as a cookie is used to "remember" the client and restore it.

If you want to reduce database load then you can implement a caching layer. In its simplest form this cache would keep in memory the last N accessed users. Your `load_user()` function then will not send queries directly into the database, it will send them to the cache. The cahe will check if a copy of the requested user is in memory and only if it isn't it grabs it from the database. Each new user loaded from the database is added to the cache, and if you reach your N limit you drop the oldest user so that you don't use too much memory.